# Marshalling Time fields as Unix time

Tags: go

I want to encode my `time.Time` fields as numeric Unix time and I would prefer not to implement custom MarshalJSON functions for each and every struct, since I have lots and lots of structs.

So, I tried defining a type alias as such:

`type Timestamp time.Time`

And implementing MarshalJSON on it like so:

```
func (t Timestamp) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(strconv.FormatInt(t.Unix(), 10)), nil
}
```

But that gives me a `t.Unix undefined (type Timestamp has no field or method Unix)`, which doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't `Timestamp` 'inherit' (I know that's probably the wrong term) all functions of `time.Time`?

I also tried using a type assertion like so:

```
strconv.FormatInt(t.(time.Time).Unix(), 10)
```

But that also fails, complaining about an invalid type assertion: `invalid type assertion: t.(time.Time) (non-interface type Timestamp on left)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your type back to a `time.Time` to have access to its methods.  Named types do not "inherit" the methods of their underlying types (to do that, you need [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)).

```
func (t Timestamp) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(strconv.FormatInt(time.Time(t).Unix(), 10)), nil
}
```

Also, just as a matter of personal preference, I tend to preferred `fmt.Sprintf("%v", i)` over `strconv.FormatInt(i, 10)` or even `strconv.Itoa(i)`.  Honestly not sure which is faster, but the `fmt` version seems easier to read, personally.